# gl_PointSize requires extension when shader version changed

Tags: opengl-es, glsl

I had GLSL shaders working fine with `#version 150 core`. The vertex shader outputted `gl_PointSize` to a triangle strip geometry shader, which uses this to indicate the size of generated objects.

I changed to `#version 300 es` and got this error

```
error C7548: 'gl_PointSize' requires "#extension GL_EXT_geometry_point_size : enable" before use
```

This is mildly surprising -- I thought extensions were normally something you needed in *older* versions to enable functionality which is provided in later versions. Now it seems like I need to recover something which was lost, but [this table](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/gl_PointSize.xhtml) seems to say that I can still use it.

What has changed which means I can't use `gl_PointSize` any more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desktop OpenGL and OpenGL ***ES*** are not the same thing. That table references desktop OpenGLx, not OpenGL ES of *any* version. If you ask for GLSL 3.00 ES, you will get [GLSL 3.00 ES](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_3.00.pdf).

Desktop GLSL 1.50 is not a lesser version of GLSL ES 3.00. Nor is it a greater version. They have no relationship to each other, except in the sense that the ES versions take stuff from the desktop versions. But even that is arbitrary, generally unrelated to version numbers.

The thing is... OpenGL ES 3.00 [*does* include `gl_PointSize`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3/html/gl_PointSize.xhtml). But it is only as an output variable from the VS. Assuming that's how your shader uses it, your implementation has a bug in its OpenGL ES support.